# Command block won't execute trigger commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm attempting to create an interface that allows players without permissions to activate commands by changing their own scoreboard value, however in order for this to work i need to reset their scoreboard number after the command has executed so the command doesn't repeat.

the player can use the command
`/trigger test set 1`
and a command block will execute a command at the player's position
However after the command has been activated i'm trying to reset the players scoreboard to zero with a command block running `execute at @a trigger test set 0` which doesn't seem to do anything

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

P.S I already have a repeat command block running `scoreboard players enable @a test` the issue command block just doesn't seem to be doing *anything*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reset the players score to `0` you will need to use `as` instead of `at`, to execute the trigger command AS the player, not at the player's location. You also forgot about the `run` literal. Here's the correct command:

```
execute as @a run trigger triggertest set 0
```

In your case you can also simply use the `scoreboard` command like this:

```
scoreboard players set @a triggertest 0
```

Or even like this, because you keep enabling it anyway, so it won't be removed from the scoreboard for longer than one tick:

```
scoreboard players reset @a
```